# pcolormesh with missing values?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have 3 1-D ndarrays: x, y, z

and the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as spinterp

## define data
npoints = 50
xreg = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),npoints)
yreg = np.linspace(y.min(),y.max(),npoints)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xreg,yreg)
Z = spinterp.griddata(np.vstack((x,y)).T,z,(X,Y),
                      method='linear').reshape(X.shape)

## plot
plt.close()
ax = plt.axes()
col = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z.T)
plt.draw()
```

My plot comes out blank, and I suspect it is because the method='linear' interpolation comes out with nans. I've tried converting to a masked array, but to no avail - plot is still blank. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Got it. This seems round-about, but this was the solution:

```
import numpy.ma as ma

Zm = ma.masked_where(np.isnan(Z),Z)
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Zm.T)
```

If the Z matrix contains `nan`'s, it has to be a masked array for `pcolormesh`, which has to be created with `ma.masked_where`, or, alternatively,

```
Zm = ma.array(Z,mask=np.isnan(Z))
```

Answer (score 18):

A slight improvement on the chosen answer

```
import numpy.ma as ma
Zm = ma.masked_invalid(Z)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Zm.T)
```

masked_invalid masks all NaN values, thereby saving the need to specify

```
mask = np.isnan(Z)
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that the explicit masking is no longer necessary in matplotlib master as arrays are now masked automatically internally. Will be incorporated into matplotlib >2.1. See my merged pull request https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5451

So now it's as simple as

```
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z.T)
```