# binned_statistic_2d producing unexpected negative values

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d` and then plotting the output. When I use `stat="count"`, I have no problems. When I use `stat="mean"` (or `np.max()` for that matter), I end up with negative values in each bin (as identified by the color bar), which should not be the case because I have constructed `zvals` such that it is always greater than zero. Does anyone know why this is the case? I've included the minimal code I use to generate the plots. I also get an invalid value `RunTime` warning, which makes me think that something strange is going on in `binned_statistic_2d`. The following code should just copy and run.

From the documentation:

```
'count' : compute the count of points within each bin.  This is
    identical to an unweighted histogram.  `values` array is not
    referenced.
```

which leads me to believe that there might be something going on in `binned_statistic_2d` and how it handles z-values.

```
import numbers as _numbers
import numpy as _np
import scipy as _scipy
import matplotlib as _mpl
import types as _types

import scipy.stats

from matplotlib import pyplot as _plt

norm_args = (0, 3, int(1e5)) # loc, scale, size

x = _np.random.random(norm_args[-1])  # xvals can be log scaled.
y = _np.random.normal(*norm_args) #_np.random.random(norm_args[-1]) #
z = _np.abs(_np.random.normal(1e2, *norm_args[1:]))

nbins = 1e2
kwargs = {}
stat = _np.max


fig, ax = _plt.subplots()

binned_stats = _scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(x, y, z, stat,
                                                nbins)
H, xedges, yedges, binnumber = binned_stats


Hplot = H
if isinstance(stat, str): 
    cbar_title = stat.title()
elif isinstance(stat, _types.FunctionType):
    cbar_title = stat.__name__.title()

XX, YY = _np.meshgrid(xedges, yedges)
Image   = ax.pcolormesh(XX, YY, Hplot.T) #norm=norm,
ax.autoscale(tight=True)

grid_kargs = {'orientation': 'vertical'}
cax, kw    = _mpl.colorbar.make_axes_gridspec(ax, **grid_kargs)
cbar       = fig.colorbar(Image, cax=cax)
cbar.set_label(cbar_title)
```

Here's the runtime warning:

```
/Users/balterma/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/matplotlib/colors.py:584: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less cbook._putmask(xa, xa < 0.0, -1)
```

Image with mean:
[image]

Image with max:
[image]

Image with count:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was interfacing with `plt.pcolormesh`. I had to convert the output array from `binned_statistic_2d` to a masked array that masked the NaNs.

Here's the question that gave me the answer:
[pcolormesh with missing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778343/pcolormesh-with-missing-values)